# How to create dummy variables for glmnet(LASSO) by model.matrix?

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I have dataset:

```
      SalesPrice SqFeet Beds Baths AirCond Garage Pool Year Quality Style  Lot     Highway
  1:      360.0  3.032    4     4       1      2    0 1972       2     1 22.221       0
  2:      340.0  2.058    4     2       1      2    0 1976       2     1 22.912       0
  3:      250.0  1.780    4     3       1      2    0 1980       2     1 21.345       0
  4:      205.5  1.638    4     2       1      2    0 1963       2     1 17.342       0
  5:      275.5  2.196    4     3       1      2    0 1968       2     7 21.786       0
```

I want to create a model:

```
model.lm2 <- glmnet(x = xvars,y = df[,SalesPrice],alpha = 1,family = 'gaussian',lambda = CV$lambda.1se)
```

But in my case I have factor variable "Style" and if I won't change it to dummy variable glmnet function will work with it as with numerical variable.

So how can I create create dummy variables for glmnet(LASSO) by model.matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [glmnetUtils](https://github.com/hong-revo/glmnetUtils) package, which will do all this for you. It's not on CRAN yet, but should be there shortly. In the meantime, use devtools to install it from the Github repo.

```
devtools::install.github("hong-revo/glmnetUtils")
library(glmnetUtils)

model.lm2 <- glmnet(SalesPrice ~ ., data=df)
```

Comment: And this function will treat with factor variable as a dummy?